# MVC raw query like and parametrization with same parameter names

Tags: oracle, model-view-controller, sql-like, prepared-statement

Using EF 5.0 with Oracle.Data.Client. Trying to execute row parametrized query.

How could multiple parameters with same param name be bound in mvc using raw query?

entities -> MVC model DB instance.

e.g.

```
string myVal = 'foo'; 
string myVal2 = '%,foo2,%'; 
string SQLstring =
  @"SELECT name 
  FROM table 
  WHERE NVL(column_1, :p0) = :p0
  AND '%,' || column_2 || ',%' LIKE :p1";

retVal = entities.Database.SqlQuery<string>(SQLstring, myVal, myVal2);
```

It is either I'm receiving:
- not all variables bound. Then I tried separate param name but not helping NVL(column_1, :p0) = :p1

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have resolved this one.

Important:
1. for some reason parameters could not have same names and have to be passed separatly NVL(column_1, :p0) = :p1
2. parameter after like needs to be in string format %,1,% (as it is in original question)

```
string myVal = 'foo';
string myVal2 = '%,foo2,%';
string SQLstring = @"SELECT name FROM table 
                        WHERE NVL(column_1, :p0) = :p1
                      AND '%,' || column_2 || ',%' LIKE :p2";
retVal = entities.Database.SqlQuery<string>(SQLstring, myVal, myVal, myVal2);
```